# Iframe blank on Safari

Tags: html, iframe, safari

I want to insert an iframe in my index page, to be more precise I have to make a cross-domain.

I did make the iframe and everything is good until I open the index page on Safari and everything is blank. I know that Safari has a feature in privacy to block cross-domain but this won't solve my problem.

I've seen other people do a cross-domain and the page loads in safari.

My HTML Code:

```
  <html>
<head>
<title> test11 </title>
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">
<meta name="description" content="keyword description goes here">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
</head>
<body>
<iframe src ="link" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get the same outcome in other browsers?

Comment: Tested it on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge and it works fine.
The strange fact is that I install Chrome on my iPhone and the page won't open, it's blank. Then I install Chrome on a  Samsung device and the page loads corectly. Am I missing something?